# Making a sub in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How could I write a program in VBA, that scans a cell range in excel(2010), than tells how many cells it scanned, and were there more numeric or text cells, and how many empty cells it found? The range cell would be defined by the user.

This is my current code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim c As Range

Set c = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="A vizsgálandó cellatartomány:", Title:="Adja meg   a cellatartományt!", Default:="A1:B4", Type:=8)

Dim szam As Integer, szoveg As Integer, osszescella As Integer, ures As Integer

osszescella = c.Cells.Count '# of scanned cells

Dim rngSpec As Range

Set rngSpec = c.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

If Not rngSpec Is Nothing Then ures = rngSpec.Cells.Count '# of blank cells

Set rngSpec = c.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2)

If Not rngSpec Is Nothing Then szoveg = rngSpec.Cells.Count '# of text cells

Set rngSpec = c.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1)

If Not rngSpec Is Nothing Then szam = rngSpec.Cells.Count '# of numeric cells

Dim kezdocella As String

kezdocella = InputBox("Kezdő cella", "Adja meg a kezdőcellát:", "G10")

Range(kezdocella).Value = "Vizsgált cellák száma: "

Range(kezdocella).Offset(0, 1).Value = osszescella

Range(kezdocella).Offset(1, 0).Value = "Szöveges/számos van több?"

If szam > szoveg Then Range(kezdocella).Offset(1, 1).Value = "Számos" _
Else: If szoveg > szam Then Range(kezdocella).Offset(1, 1).Value = "Szöveges" _
Else Range(kezdocella).Offset(1, 1).Value = "Ugyanannyi van"

Range(kezdocella).Offset(2, 0).Value = "Üres cellák száma: "

Range(kezdocella).Offset(2, 1).Value = ures

Range(kezdocella).Offset(3, 0).Value = "Nem üres cellák száma: "

Range(kezdocella).Offset(3, 1).Value = osszescella - ures

Cells.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Works fine now, thank you Scott Holtzman. In the end, it shows the result starting from a cell the user gives. I'm sure there would be a better way to do it, but I this works too I guess.

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking questions you are more likely to get a good response if you tell people what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a great start! I have helped you in the code below as well as cleaned up some of your syntax which was invalid. This should get you were you want to go ... and without the unnecessary looping.

```
Option Explicit

Sub elsobeadando()

Dim c As Range

Set c = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Cell Range", Title:="Specify Range", Type:=8)

Dim szam As Integer, szoveg As Integer, osszescella As Integer, ures As Integer

szam = c.Cells.Count '# of scanned cells

On Error Resume Next
Dim rngSpec As Range
Set rngSpec = c.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

If Not rngSpec Is Nothing Then szoveg = rngSpec.Cells.Count '# of blank cells

Set rngSpec = c.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2)

If Not rngSpec Is Nothing Then osszescella = rngSpec.Cells.Count '# of text cells

Set rngSpec = c.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1)

If Not rngSpec Is Nothing Then ures = rngSpec.Cells.Count '# of numeric cells

'not sure if this maps up with the above because, well ... I don't understand hungarian! :)
'also cleaned this up a bit to be actual VBA syntax
Range("D10").Value = osszescella
If szam > szoveg Then Range("D11").Value = "Több számos cella volt, mint szöveges"
Range("D12").Value = ures
Range("D13").Value = osszescella - ures

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate it. I will try to add to the end, that it shows the result where the user wants, I hope I can do it with "copying" the solutions from you.